# PHP Not uploading submitted data to the db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm fairly sure I've only made a simple mistake, yet I am having troubles finding it. Basically, whenever someone fills in a normal form, the data they enter is submitted to the db table, to be later posted on another page of the site. However, that does not seem to be working.

If possible, I'd just like some help in the right direction about what I've actually done wrong.

Thanks in advance, I hope this post isn't too annoying. I'm new here :,)

PHP:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
        $match_name = strip_tags($_POST['match_name']);
            $team1 = strip_tags($_POST['team1']);
                $player1 = strip_tags($_POST['player1']);
                $player2 = strip_tags($_POST['player2']);
                $player3 = strip_tags($_POST['player3']);
                $player4 = strip_tags($_POST['player4']);
                $player5 = strip_tags($_POST['player5']);

            $team2 = strip_tags($_POST['team2']);
                $player6 = strip_tags($_POST['player6']);
                $player7 = strip_tags($_POST['player7']);
                $player8 = strip_tags($_POST['player8']);
                $player9 = strip_tags($_POST['player9']);
                $player10 = strip_tags($_POST['player10']);

        $match_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $match_name);
            $team1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $team1);
                $player1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player1);
                $player2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player2);
                $player3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player3);
                $player4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player4);
                $player5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player5);
            $team2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $team2);
                $player6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player6);
                $player7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player7);
                $player8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player8);
                $player9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player9);
                $player10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $player10);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `match` (match_name, team1, player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, team2, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10) VALUES ('$team1, '$player1', '$player2', '$player3', '$player4', '$player5', '$team2, '$player6', '$player7', '$player8', '$player9', '$player10')";              

        if($match_name == "") {
            echo "You're missing a title for varible <strong>Match Title</strong> | <a href='post.php'>Go back</a>";
            return;
        }

        if($team1 == "") {
            echo "You're missing a title for varible <strong>Team 1 Name</strong> | <a href='post.php'>Go back</a>";
            return;
        }

        if($team2 == "") {
            echo "You're missing a title for varible <strong>Team 2 Name</strong>";
            return;
        }

        mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: You really should start reading about "prepared statements" and the benefits of "parameter binding"... But first of all you want to fix your current issue. For that you need to find out what is wrong. Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where php logs errors to. There is no sense in trying to _guess_ what _might_ be wrong, if you can simply read what _is_ wrong in that file.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Error logs showed no errors relevant to this problem and I'm getting no errors shown with the error reporting inserted.

Comment: As an aside, unrelated to your question, never use `==`, use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Moving forward from everything @arkascha and @Jay Blanchard already mentioned.

You missing the single quotes `'` in your SQL query near `VALUES` of `'$team1` and `'$team2`  :

Instead of this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `match` (match_name, team1, player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, 
team2, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10) 
VALUES ('$team1, '$player1', '$player2', '$player3', '$player4', '$player5', 
'$team2, '$player6', '$player7', '$player8', '$player9', '$player10')";
```

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `match` (match_name, team1, player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, 
team2, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10) 
VALUES ('$team1', '$player1', '$player2', '$player3', '$player4', '$player5', 
'$team2', '$player6', '$player7', '$player8', '$player9', '$player10')";
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't seemed to make a difference.

Comment: what is this if(isset($_POST['post'])) {. Do, you have any thing namely post in form

Comment: @ZeddZeppelin Please add your connection.php and HTML in your question too.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Was this answer not the solution to _one_ of the problems OP had in the question?